# Does anyone know how to configure eclipse NOT to copy font colors / background when doing CTRL+C

Tags: windows, eclipse

Does anyone know how to configure eclipse NOT to copy font colors / background when doing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>?

Not that I would ever cut and paste code. I'm really asking this for a friend :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it can be set in Eclipse - I suspect not (I've looked and not found it). What works for me is to paste to an editor that doesn't accept the colours, such as Notepad, and then copy from there and paste in the destination. A little tedious (but it works!), I know, so I'll be watching this to see if someone else has a better solution. ;)

Comment: Yeah, this is what I always have done, and today I figured there had to be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

There are many utilities out there that will remove the clipboard text formatting. Personally, I'm on a Mac and I use [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) that can do that among other things. Searching the web yields many results, for example [this one](http://www.clipboardfusion.com/) which is free.

I prefer "plain text paste" in many applications, regardless of the origin. Some programs have a "Paste and Match Style" option. If you can customize the shortcuts in the program, I usually switch the Ctrl-V to "Paste and Match Style" instead of "Paste" and assign Shift+Ctrl+V to "Paste".